# How can I determine the name of the Android namespace using XmlPullParser?

Tags: android, parsing, android-layout, xml-parsing

I'm parsing Android layout files, and I'd like to figure out what the user may have called the Android namespace (just in case it isn't just `android` as is typical). How would I go about figuring this prefix out? Is there a "get all prefixes" method in XmlPullParser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution, though it isn't pretty. The android namespace proper is found at `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`. Doing the following, I can match the prefixes of the attributes to the namespace:

```
String prefix = xpp.getAttributePrefix(i);
if (xpp.getNamespace(prefix) == "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android") {
    // We found it! Save the value of prefix
}
```

In the above code, i would be the index of an element's attribute having a prefix.

I managed to circumvent this by simply using `xpp.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", attr);`to find what I wanted regardless of the actual prefix.